# Compare string in Bash

Tags: bash, devops

i write script for Elasticsearch backup, and after the backup is complete I want to see if the data (indexes) has actually been backed up
Every day, certain indexes are created in elasticsearch that I want to backup, and when I run the script for backup, I insert these indexes into a variable (for example, a snippet from my script)

```
_DATE=$(date '+%Y.%m.%d')
_UZBEKISTAN_INDICES=$(curl -s -X GET "localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v" | grep 'tashkent-'$_DATE'\|fergana-'$_DATE'' | awk '{ print $3 }')
```

and if we do echo _ $ UZBEKISTAN_INDICES in the script then the output will be like this

```
tashkent-2021.09.20 fergana-2021.09.20
```

To check the backup There is an output with a list of indexes that were backed up

```
curl -s -XGET "localhost:9200/_snapshot/uzbekistan-2021.09.20/uzbekistan-2021.09.20/?pretty"
{
  "snapshots" : [
    {
      "snapshot" : "uzbekistan-2021.09.20",
      "uuid" : "CLDZ6bLpS06s37tUKNwxpg",
      "version_id" : 7040099,
      "version" : "7.4.0",
      "indices" : [
        "tashkent-2021.09.20",
        "fergana-2021.09.20"
      ],
      "include_global_state" : false,
      "metadata" : {
        "taken_by" : "kimchy",
        "taken_because" : "backup before upgrading"
      },
      "state" : "SUCCESS",
      "start_time" : "2021-09-20T07:00:06.272Z",
      "start_time_in_millis" : 1632121206272,
      "end_time" : "2021-09-20T07:00:06.472Z",
      "end_time_in_millis" : 1632121206472,
      "duration_in_millis" : 200,
      "failures" : [ ],
      "shards" : {
        "total" : 2,
        "failed" : 0,
        "successful" : 2
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I think that it would be more correct to check which indexes were backed up and compare them with the contents of the _ $ UZBEKISTAN_INDICES variable

```
"indices" : [
       "tashkent-2021.09.20",
       "fergana-2021.09.20"
     ],
```

so how can i compare this?

Comment: To work with JSON use JSON aware tool. Like `jq`.

Comment: @noze_potato : Your grep pattern looks a bit odd to me.  In the part `'\|fergana-'` , the backslash is a literal backslash, because you are between single quotes, and the backslash would escape only another backslash. There is no need to escape a `|`, because you are between quotes anyway.

Comment: @user1934428 I escape variable '$_DATE'

Comment: `$_DATE` is outside any quotes. There is no meaning saying to _escape_ it. You are passing `tashkent-`, followed by the content of varialbe `_DATE`, followed by `\|fergana-`, followed again by the content of `_DATE`, redundantly followed by a null string (`''`).

Comment: @user1934428 okay send me please right variant

Comment: @noze_potato: I don't know exactly how you want your grep pattern to look like, and in particular what role the vertical bar plays in the pattern. Perhaps `"tashkent-$_DATE|fergana-$_DATE"` is what you mean, but I don't think you have any vertical bar in your input data.

Comment: If you want to match *either* tashkent *or* fergana, the bar makes sense, but **only** if you use the `-E`  option of _grep_: `grep -E "(tashkent|fergana)-$_DATE"`, but note that since _DATE contains periods, these periods would match **any** single letter. You would have to escape these periods, to avoid a false match.